# Add different animation for different frame in video using ffmpeg android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-animation, slideshow, fadein

I am trying to apply animations for the particular video frame but hereby I'm not seeing that video frame by which I have to apply the animation. I only need fade in and fade out frame and display it as slide show video. Do you have any idea about this?

for ex: I want to create an application like this one : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scoompa.slideshow

[I am using the same command which was given to this url but for the particular 5 second video hide and not getting slide show effect.](http://www.bogotobogo.com/FFMpeg/ffmpeg_fade_in_fade_out_transitions_effects_filters.php)

Comment: Is this a programming question, or is this question about the usage of ffmpeg? (That goes to a different site, such as askubuntu.)

Comment: yes.its regarding command but i am using in android and not getting animation effect on each frame so upload here.